# Regex to remove empty lines and timestamp from subtitle file

Tags: regex

I have a downloaded subtitle file like below.The file contains line numbers,empty lines and timestamp. i want to remove these line number,empty line and timestamp, i need just the text only

**What it is now**

```
1
00:00:01.876 --> 00:00:02.709
<v Instructor>We can go back now</v>

2
00:00:02.709 --> 00:00:05.042
to our web server checklist.

3
00:00:06.410 --> 00:00:08.722
We've already seen better ways to organise our code

4
00:00:08.722 --> 00:00:11.545
into reusable pieces with modules,

5
00:00:11.545 --> 00:00:13.315
we've seen ways to deal with files,

6
00:00:13.315 --> 00:00:15.940
both synchronous and asynchronous,

7
00:00:15.940 --> 00:00:16.773
and buffers,

8
00:00:16.773 --> 00:00:18.325
both the built-in Node one

9
00:00:18.325 --> 00:00:20.380
and the ES6 buffers,

10
00:00:20.380 --> 00:00:22.485
and we've seen a way to deal with work
```

**what the output should be**

We can go back nowto our web server checklist.We've already seen better ways to organise our codeinto reusable pieces with modules,we've seen ways to deal with files,both synchronous and asynchronous,and buffers,both the built-in Node oneand the ES6 buffers,and we've seen a way to deal with work

Guys please help me out how to achieve this,i am using [this](https://regex101.com/) online tool to achieve this

Comment: You didn't save your regex. You have to save it, then share the link here. And not only the link, you should actually show here what you tried, just in case the link becomes unavailable.

Comment: By the way: wouldn't it be much easier to just take every fourth line, starting with the third?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thats a different way of thinking superb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to do the following :

1. Select the lines beginning either by a number or a newline character.
2. Select everything in the line until the end
3. Also select the new-line character at the end of the line

The following regex does this exactly

```
^[\d\n].*\n
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKY2no/2/)**

*Little disclaimer : this will exclude the lines of text beginning with a number*

---

### Output

```
<v Instructor>We can go back now</v>
to our web server checklist.
We've already seen better ways to organise our code
into reusable pieces with modules,
we've seen ways to deal with files,
both synchronous and asynchronous,
and buffers,
both the built-in Node one
and the ES6 buffers,
and we've seen a way to deal with work
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use more than one regexp - sequentially on results of previous regexp. Here is developed **[@YassinHajaj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50348864/860099)** answer (regexp to remove numbers and times) to get desired output

```
^[\d\n].*\n               remove numbers and times                             
\<\/?v.*?\>               remove <v> tag
\R                        join multi lines into one line
```

Here are links to sequence of regexp used in this tool [1](https://regex101.com/r/QfXx5l/1) -> [2](https://regex101.com/r/n91Sg8/1) -> [3](https://regex101.com/r/o3wJpp/1).

**Output**

Is exactly what you want

*We can go back now to our web server checklist. We've already seen better ways to organise our code into reusable pieces with modules, we've seen ways to deal with files, both synchronous and asynchronous, and buffers, both the built-in Node one and the ES6 buffers, and we've seen a way to deal with work*

Answer (score 1):

The following will select all lines with the text (even the last line):

```
^[a-zA-z]*.*(\n|\Z)$
```

1. `[a-zA-z]*` selects all lines starting with a character (zero or more times)
2. `.*` any char (zero or more times)
3. `(\n|\Z)` end of line or EOF

You can view it at your [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/mGSwvS/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a definitive regex based on your exact needs: `(?:(?:[\n$]|^\d+$)|(?:^[\n\s])|(?:\d{1,3}(?:[:.\d$]|(?:\s(?=-))))|(?:--> ))+`

As an improvement over other answers, it will even work for lines starting with numbers (single digits at the moment), matching nnn:nnn formats. Try it here:
https://regex101.com/r/din5tp/1/

But it is very far from perfection.

For an explaination on how it works, I recommend using the tool.

It is to be noted that any regex will ultimately have weaknesses and I don't recommend this level of complexity unless this is what you really need.

Output:

*We can go back nowto our web server checklist.We've already seen better ways to organise our codeinto reusable pieces with modules,we've seen ways to deal with files,both synchronous and asynchronous,and buffers,both the built-in Node oneand the ES6 buffers,and we've seen a way to deal with work*

Comment: I am glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
^[(\d|\n)].*$
```

This pattern removes every empty line or lines starting with a digit

Comment: I don't think you meant to negate your character class